# VBA code for string pattern match in a column in Excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Please post the VBA code.

We will get Report in Excel sheet consting of 17 columns and i want to take out items after matching string pattern in column 'K' in sheet1.

Below is the sample of column 'K' items

heroine
I am hero, I am zero, I am villan
hero
villan
heroine
I am hero, I am zero, I am villan
villan, heroine
hero, villan
actor
zero
I am hero, I am zero

Now i have applied filter to column 'K' and then->text filter-> contains->then given pattern *hero*zero*(which selects all strings which contains hero & zero).

Below is the recorded macro for above action.

```
Sub Macro1()  
'  
' Macro1 Macro  
'  

'
    Columns("H:H").Select  
    Selection.AutoFilter  
    ActiveSheet.Range("$H$1:$H$12").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _  
        "=****hero*zero****", Operator:=xlAnd  
End Sub
```

And now the result i got is ( in column 'K' of same sheet(sheet1) )

I am hero, I am zero, I am villan
I am hero, I am zero, I am villan
I am hero, I am zero

---

I want VBA code to perform above action and i want the above result( it should contains 17 columns, which are in sheet1)  in Sheet2.
Please help me on the above.
 Thanks in Advance.

Comment: +1 for taking the effort to improving the question as suggested :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

neobee, Now your question makes more sense :)

Try the below.

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowWs As Long
    Dim Rng As Range

    '~~> Set your Input Sheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    '~~> Get the lastrow in Sheet1
    LastRowWs = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Range("A1"), _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    '~~> Filter the Range
    ws.Range("A1:K" & LastRowWs).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
    "=*hero*zero*", Operator:=xlAnd

    With ws.AutoFilter.Range
        On Error Resume Next
        '~~> Set the copy range [17 to include all 17 columns]
        Set Rng = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 17) _
                   .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '~~> There is no match found
    If Rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "There is no data which matches the '*hero*zero*' criteria"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '~~> Prepare sheet 2 for output
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Clear

    '~~> Copy the cells
    Rng.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")

    '~~> Remove autofilter from Input sheet
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddarth, it is working fine. Thanks for your valuable time

Answer (score 1):

I can't debug the code right now, but something like this should do:

```
Sub filter_and_copy()   
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _  
        "=*hero*zero*", Operator:=xlAnd 
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:R").SpecialCells(xlvisible).Copy Destination:= _
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub
```